# [MsTeams][BotFrameworkV4][Adaptive Card ] Scrollable Adaptive card in teams

Tags: .net, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Can we have Scrollable Adaptive card in Bot framework and Ms teams.

I have found it in "who Bot" in Teams which is having scrollable adaptive card and I want to render the same card in my bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Chekrii Adaptive cards cannot be scrollable. If you want to show additional information you can open a new card from the existing card using [Showcard action](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.ShowCard.html). You could also try using carousel to render your card. The image that you have pasted is not an Adaptive card. This is a [list card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#list-card) which provides a scrolling list of items.

Comment: Thanks you so much it helped